# Authlogic + Rails3 - undefined method `Login' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, rvm

Im new to Rails, and decided to start of with Rails3. After a lot of searching ive managed to get a little bit of Authlogic working. I'm able to register a user, login & logout.

Now, I would like to add more features, get more of authlogic working. I'm using [Railscast EP 160](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic) as my reference.

Portions of the code found on the tutorial throw errors:
Eg:

```
<!-- layouts/_topbar.erb -->
<%= link_to "Login", login_path %>
```

and I get the following error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `login_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000311e8f8>:0x0000000310af38>
```

To overcome this, ive just used a string. i.e. <%= link_to "Login", "/UserSessions/new" %>

Now it seems like i've reached an impasse. When i try to output the current user with:

```
<%= @user.Login %>
```

I get an error that im unable to circumvent. Can you please help me? Thanks :) Please find below the error message, and some of the code.

```
undefined method `Login' for nil:NilClass
```

Full Trace Reads [truncated]

```
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
app/views/layouts/_topbar.erb:16:in `_app_views_layouts__topbar_erb__4536428193941102933_40950340__3781575178692065315'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/render/partials.rb:294:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/render/partials.rb:223:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
```

Request Parameters:None

My gemfile reads:

```
gem "authlogic", :git => "git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git", :branch => "rails3"
```

config/routes.rb:

```
  resources :users
  resources :user_sessions
  resources :ibe
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

controllers/application_controller.rb:
[the part that gets the current user.. also taken from online examples]

```
  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end
```

models/user_session.rb:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
include ActiveModel::Conversion
  def persisted?
    false
  end
  def to_key
    new_record? ? nil : [ self.send(self.class.primary_key) ]
  end
end
```

models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_no_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :require_user, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Account registered!"
      redirect_back_or_default account_url
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = @current_user

  end

  def edit
    @user = @current_user

  end

  def update
    @user = @current_user # makes our views "cleaner" and more consistent
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = "Account updated!"
      redirect_to account_url
    else
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end


end
```

Okay, I decided to switch to Devise.. seems to work out of the box with rails 3.. yaay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user isn't logged in, so @user is nil.  Put some logic like you see in the example Rails3 app here.

http://github.com/trevmex/authlogic_rails3_example/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Note I am using this branch for authlogic for rails3, although I'm not sure if it's any better or worse than the main branch.

http://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic/tree/rails3

Also note I tried rails3 with the railscast 160, but it's out of date.  I had more luck using the railscast just for basic orientation, and then sticking with the example app from trevmex on github above for the actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks peter! I wish i had stuck on a bit longer to see your reply..but i just gave up on authlogic and went with devise.. seems good till now.